# In .NET how to dynamically evaluate a complex expression against an object?

Tags: .net, reflection, dynamic

In C#, imagine I have the following object:

```
var myObject = new
{
    Val = new[]
    {
        new { ArrVal = "three1"},
        new { ArrVal = "three2"}
    }
};
```

How would I dynamically evaluate the following expression against the object? (**the expression is a string**)

```
"Val[1].ArrVal"
```

In this case I would expect the expression to return "three2". I'd like to write a method with the following signature:

```
object GetValue(string expression, object objectToExtractValueFrom)
```

Can I do this with reflection, or somehow with the dynamic keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it either with reflection or with dynamic keyword. What you can do is:

1. parse the string in order to create an lambda expression tree that
   will be compiled and executed against your parameter(s)
2. use CodeDOM
3. use some dynamic language like IronRuby or IronPython

Comment: +1 although even with python and ruby string evaluation is a bad thing.

Comment: In my opinion, that depends on where this string comes from. It shouldn't come from users, that's for sure. After all, string evaluation is what the question is about. Thanks for the plus.

Comment: from the user it would be a dramatic security problem. Otherwise it is very often a bad design.

Comment: With this I agree. However some situations do require a form of custom scripting.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually to map domain object properties to auto-populated PDF files. I'll rather go the more static route and have predefined keys that you can use (that map to specified properties).

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the Spring.Core NuGet package
2. Use the ExpressionEvaluator class (see http://www.springframework.net/doc/reference/html/expressions.html)

Examples:

```
ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue("Test", "Length.ToString().Length");
ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "DateTime.Now")
```